# How Can I Unit Test Swift Timer Controller?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, timer, mocking

I am working a project that will utilize Swift's `Timer` class. My `TimerController` class will control a `Timer` instance by starting, pausing, resuming, and resetting it.

`TimerController` consists of the following code:

```swift
internal final class TimerController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var timer = Timer()
    private let timerIntervalInSeconds = TimeInterval(1)
    internal private(set) var durationInSeconds: TimeInterval

    // MARK: - Initialization

    internal init(seconds: Double) {
        durationInSeconds = TimeInterval(seconds)
    }

    // MARK: - Timer Control

    // Starts and resumes the timer
    internal func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerIntervalInSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimerFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    internal func pauseTimer() {
        invalidateTimer()
    }

    internal func resetTimer() {
        invalidateTimer()
        durationInSeconds = 0
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    @objc private func handleTimerFire() {
        durationInSeconds += 1
    }

    private func invalidateTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Currently, my `TimerControllerTests` contains the following code:

```swift
class TimerControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    func test_TimerController_DurationInSeconds_IsSet() {
        let expected: TimeInterval = 60
        let controller = TimerController(seconds: 60)
        XCTAssertEqual(controller.durationInSeconds, expected, "'durationInSeconds' is not set to correct value.")
    }

}
```

I am able to test that the timer's expected duration is set correctly when initializing an instance of `TimerController`. However, I don't know where to start testing the rest of `TimerController`.

I want to ensure that the class successfully handles `startTimer()`, `pauseTimer()`, and `resetTimer()`. I want my unit tests to run as quickly as possible, but I think that I need to actually start, pause, and stop the timer to test that the `durationInSeconds` property is updated after the appropriate methods are called.

Is it appropriate to actually create the timer in `TimerController` and call the methods in my unit tests to verify that `durationInSeconds` has been updated correctly?

I realize that it will slow my unit tests down, but I don't know of another way to appropriately test this class and it's intended actions.

**Update**

I have been doing some research, and I have found, what I think to be, a solution that seems to get the job done as far as my testing goes. However, I am unsure whether this implementation is sufficient.

I have reimplemented my `TimerController` as follows:

```swift
internal final class TimerController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var timer = Timer()
    private let timerIntervalInSeconds = TimeInterval(1)
    internal private(set) var durationInSeconds: TimeInterval
    internal var isTimerValid: Bool {
        return timer.isValid
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    internal init(seconds: Double) {
        durationInSeconds = TimeInterval(seconds)
    }

    // MARK: - Timer Control

    internal func startTimer(fireCompletion: (() -> Void)?) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerIntervalInSeconds, repeats: true, block: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.durationInSeconds -= 1
            fireCompletion?()
        })
    }

    internal func pauseTimer() {
        invalidateTimer()
    }

    internal func resetTimer() {
        invalidateTimer()
        durationInSeconds = 0
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    private func invalidateTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Also, my test file has passing tests:

```swift
class TimerControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var timerController: TimerController!

    // MARK: - Setup

    override func setUp() {
        timerController = TimerController(seconds: 1)
    }

    // MARK: - Teardown

    override func tearDown() {
        timerController.resetTimer()
        super.tearDown()
    }

    // MARK: - Time

    func test_TimerController_DurationInSeconds_IsSet() {
        let expected: TimeInterval = 60
        let timerController = TimerController(seconds: 60)
        XCTAssertEqual(timerController.durationInSeconds, expected, "'durationInSeconds' is not set to correct value.")
    }

    func test_TimerController_DurationInSeconds_IsZeroAfterTimerIsFinished() {
        let numberOfSeconds: TimeInterval = 1
        let durationExpectation = expectation(description: "durationExpectation")
        timerController = TimerController(seconds: numberOfSeconds)
        timerController.startTimer(fireCompletion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + numberOfSeconds, execute: {
            durationExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertEqual(0, self.timerController.durationInSeconds, "'durationInSeconds' is not set to correct value.")
        })
        waitForExpectations(timeout: numberOfSeconds + 1, handler: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Timer State

    func test_TimerController_TimerIsValidAfterTimerStarts() {
        let timerValidityExpectation = expectation(description: "timerValidity")
        timerController.startTimer {
            timerValidityExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertTrue(self.timerController.isTimerValid, "Timer is invalid.")
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
    }

    func test_TimerController_TimerIsInvalidAfterTimerIsPaused() {
        let timerValidityExpectation = expectation(description: "timerValidity")
        timerController.startTimer {
            self.timerController.pauseTimer()
            timerValidityExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertFalse(self.timerController.isTimerValid, "Timer is valid")
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
    }

    func test_TimerController_TimerIsInvalidAfterTimerIsReset() {
        let timerValidityExpectation = expectation(description: "timerValidity")
        timerController.startTimer {
            self.timerController.resetTimer()
            timerValidityExpectation.fulfill()
            XCTAssertFalse(self.timerController.isTimerValid, "Timer is valid")
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
    }

}
```

The only thing that I can think of to make the tests faster is for me to mock the class and change `let timerIntervalInSeconds = TimeInterval(1)` to `private let timerIntervalInSeconds = TimeInterval(0.1)`.

Is it overkill to mock the class so that I can use a smaller time interval for testing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than use a real timer (which would be slow), we can verify calls to a test double.

The challenge is that the code calls a factory method, `Timer.scheduledTimer(…)`. This locks down a dependency. Testing would be easier if the test could provide a mock timer instead.

Usually, a good way to inject a factory is by supplying a closure. We can do this in the initializer, and provide a default value. Then the closure, by default, will make the actual call to the factory method.

In this case, it's a little complicated because the call to `Timer.scheduledTimer(…)` itself takes a closure:

```
internal init(seconds: Double,
              makeRepeatingTimer: @escaping (TimeInterval, @escaping (TimerProtocol) -> Void) -> TimerProtocol = {
                  return Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: $0, repeats: true, block: $1)
              }) {
    durationInSeconds = TimeInterval(seconds)
    self.makeRepeatingTimer = makeRepeatingTimer
}
```

Note that I removed all references to `Timer` except inside the block. Everywhere else uses a newly-defined `TimerProtocol`.

`self.makeRepeatingTimer` is a closure property. Call it from `startTimer(…)`.

Now test code can supply a different closure:

```
class TimerControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    var makeRepeatingTimerCallCount = 0
    var lastMockTimer: MockTimer?

    func testSomething() {
        let sut = TimerController(seconds: 12, makeRepeatingTimer: { [unowned self] interval, closure in
            self.makeRepeatingTimerCallCount += 1
            self.lastMockTimer = MockTimer(interval: interval, closure: closure)
            return self.lastMockTimer!
        })

        // call something on sut

        // verify against makeRepeatingTimerCallCount and lastMockTimer
    }
}
```